# Validate regex 24h plus null not working in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm using this to validate a 24h time format:

```
'start_time' => ['regex:/^(([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])|null/'],
```

But Laravel doesn't like it and return as not validated

I've tested the code on https://regex101.com/ and it's working correctly, am I missing something? The problem is with the null, because if I take it out, then the hour validator is fine, but not the null

BTW start_time is empty and Laravel convert it into null

Comment: Could you post examples of inputs that gives correct output and the ones that does not?

Comment: Don't use a regex for that. Use `date_format` and if it doesn't suffice build a custom function to deal with edge cases.

Comment: not sure why is duplicated, but well. Answering the other question, 12:04 works good, leaving the input empty drops

Comment: Correct, and that is what I'm doing, using the array for that..

Answer (score 2):

Just use laravels date format function

```
'start_time' => 'nullable|date_format:H:i',
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-date-format)

Comment: Thanks, the problem here is that sometimes the user enters 00:00 AM, so with date_format:H:i I can't validate that, that's why I'm using regex

Comment: 00:00 will pass, and in 24 hour there is no 00:00 AM only 00:00